# How to compare if two elements are the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to compare if the two td elements are the same within 1 `table`.

I have

```
 var element = $('.table td'); 

 $('table:odd td','.table').each(function(){
   if(element.is(this)){
      console.log('find')
   }  
 )}
```

I want to check if the element is the same as this but my codes don't seem to work here.

Can anyone give me a hint for it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regular DOM nodes can be compared against each other, and using get(0) will get you the first DOM node from the jQuery collection :

```
var element = $('.table td'); 

$('table:odd td','.table').each(function(){
   if (element.get(0) === this ){
      console.log('find');
   }  
});
```

It does look like `element` would contain more than one element, especially as you're iterating the same selector with an added `:odd` on the next line, so the comparison seems a little strange, and will probably return false ?

Comment: Might want to fix that syntax error: It should be }) instead of ')}'

Comment: No problem, just comes from lots of practice making bonehead syntax errors!